# Convert and optimize c# linq to sql code by join

Tags: c#, sql, join, linq-to-sql

I have some code in c# linq and want to convert it to join(optimize speed).

exp:
1- first it gets 2 param (a.fromDate b.toDate)
2- for each date wanna load all pathCodes(table)
3- for each (date-paths) I check if pathrep(table) exists in that date, IF exists load it
4. else load nearest Paths(table)
5. Paths(table) and pathreps(table) have same columns

```
for (var date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            IDictionary<string, CPath> paths_dic = new Dictionary<string, CPath>();

            foreach (var path_code_class in db.PathCodes)
            {
                PathRep rep = null;                    

                var db_path_reps = db.PathReps.Where(p => p.path_code == path_code_class.path_code && p.rep_start == date );
                if (db_path_reps.Count() > 0)
                {
                    rep = db_path_reps.First();

                    CPath cpath = new CPath();
                    cpath.PathId            =   rep.ID;
                    cpath.PathCode          =   rep.path_code;
                    cpath.PathGroupName     =   rep.path_group_name;
                    ....

                    paths_dic.Add(rep.path_code, cpath);
                }
                else
                {
                    var path = db.Paths.Where(p => p.path_code_id == path_code_class.Id && p.start_date <= date ).OrderByDescending(p => p.start_date).First();
                    
                    CPath cpath = new CPath();

                    cpath.PathId            = path.ID;
                    cpath.PathCode          = path.path_code;
                    cpath.PathGroupName     = path.path_group_name;
                    ...

                    paths_dic.Add(path.path_code, cpath);
                }
            }
            dPaths_dic.Add(shamsi_date_int, paths_dic);
        }
```

This code is very messy and not optimized. I want use join but my ways didn't work correctly.

Thank you so much

Comment: What is the success ratio of finding a record in path reps? How many records in path reps?

Comment: for each date and the each pathcode maybe there is on path rep, if not we must load nearest path

Comment: Yeah, I got that part. I'm asking what percentage do have on path rep? 1% ? 50%? 99%? And how many records in path rep table? 10? 100? Million?

Comment: almost 20% is path reps, all pathcodes is 400, for each day approximately we have  80 pathreps. report is for 1 month, means from 12000 records, 2400 is for pathreps, other must be fetch from paths

Comment: It sounds like a small enough number of records treat it might make sense to download all the pathreps that could apply (date range), into a dictionary, then you can say ContainsKey and know whether to hit db for "nearest". Having some sample data would help form queries; i'm thinking another query could be used to give every nearest. All in for fastest performance I think you might get most out of it to do it as a raw sql. People in the sql tag would do all the work if you just post example data and give the logic(sql tag is a bit more weird than others; we don't insist people try themselves)